# Selenium loop through list and make same actions with every element with java

Tags: java, loops, selenium, for-loop

I`ve seen many info regarding how to implement loops, but I still did not find anything that would solve my problem.
Process of a test:

1. click on username (which is a link)
2. uncheck a checkbox for the first groupname
3. check a checkbox for the next groupname
4. click saving button (after that you are being automatically redirected to a page with users list and assigned groups)
5. check that that same name of a group is seen as was assigned
6. repeat

I have written a test that does all those steps in repeatable step-by-step form, but it would be better to turn it into a loop and that where I encounter a problem. For now my code looks like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("testUser")).click();
WebElement parent = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/app-root/app-admin-edit-user-profile/main/div[2]/div/form/section[2]/div[2]"));  
List<WebElement> children = parent.findElements(By.className("custom-checkbox"));    
for(int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) {
    children.get(i).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    avp.getSaveBtn().click();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("testUser")).click();
}
```

And it clicks on the user name, clicks on the first group, clicks on it again and clicks save button, and the stops. So basically it performs one action with one group and stops. Could anyone help with that?

Comment: First of all, I would remove hard code ("testUser"). If you are using some test users names, better to keep list of names in some array or list.

Comment: Hi! Yes, sure I am not going to leave it hardcoded, I have data.properties for test usernames.

Comment: When clicking the link for user, is a new page opened? For me, is is not quite clear, where the check and uncheck group part is? Maybe you can add comments.

Comment: Yes, when you click on a username a new page is opened and there you have a list of user groups that you choose by checking a checkbox,